# Pandas: Hierarchical group by with bins

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'd like to aggregate data in a pandas dataframe by binning dimensions hierarchically and representing the bins by some aggregate/representative.
When trying it in the following way, an exception is raised indicating an issue with overlapping indices.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
   'A': [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4],
   'B': [5,7,5,6,7,7,6,7],
   'C': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
})

A_grouped = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2) 
# groups: (0.997, 2.5], (2.5, 4.0]

B_grouped = df.groupby([A_grouped])['B'].apply(pd.cut, bins=2)
# groups: (0.997, 2.5]: (4.998, 6.0], (6.0, 7.0]
#         (2.5, 4.0]: (5.999, 6.5], (6.5, 7.0]

df_agg = df.groupby([A_grouped, B_grouped], as_index=False).agg(**{ 
        'A': ('A', 'min'), 
        'B': ('B', 'mean'), 
        'C': ('C', 'median'),
    })
# raises exception: cannot handle overlapping indices; use IntervalIndex.get_indexer_non_unique

print(df_agg)

# expected output
# A, B, C
# 1, 5.333, 1
# 1, 7, 1
# 3, 6, 1
# 3, 7, 1
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems `pandas` has an issue creating a MultiIndex when there are intervals on multiple levels. Since your output doesn't care about the groups, specify `labels=False` when you `pd.cut` then grouping works as the grouping keys are simple integers.

```
A_grouped = pd.cut(df['A'], bins=2, labels=False) 
B_grouped = df.groupby([A_grouped])['B'].apply(pd.cut, bins=2, labels=False)

df_agg = (df.groupby([A_grouped, B_grouped], as_index=False)
             .agg(**{'A': ('A', 'min'), 
                     'B': ('B', 'mean'), 
                     'C': ('C', 'median')}))

#   A         B  C
#0  1  5.333333  1
#1  1  7.000000  1
#2  4  6.000000  1    # <- Your expected A was wrong. 
#3  3  7.000000  1
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved the issue. You are right, with the given approach A must be 4 for row index 2. What if I wanted to have the min of all values for that bin, so in that case 3?